# Bootstrap - How to make text wrap around an image on small devices?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just getting started with Bootstrap. Below is a snapshot of my page.

[image]

My CSS is

```
.snippet img{
width: 150px;
max-width: 100%;
height:auto;


 }

@media(max-width: 767px) {
.snippet img{

    width:100px;
    float: right;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<h2>About the venue</h2>
<div class="media-body snippet" >
    <a class="pull-right" href="venue.php">
            <img  src="images/venue.jpg" alt="illustration"></a>
    <p>this is the paragraph ... </p>       
</div>
```

I want the image to be hanging like that on big screen. However, on small devices I would like to get the text to wrap around the image. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why you dont use this? its also smarter ;)
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content

**EDIT**

include code from bootstrap doc

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">

        <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

            <p>...</p>

            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice! But the image and text become really close if I use this. Any idea on how to insert a space?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using? if you are using 2.3.2 you have to edit the code above.

Comment: His question is asking about wrapping text to the side; that Bootstrap styling puts the image above the text.

Comment: Indeed, it puts the text below.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can try this

```
<style>
    .snippet {width: 250px;}
    .snippet img{ width: 150px; height:auto; float: left; }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<div class="media-body" >
    <div class="snippet">
        <a class="pull-right" href="venue.php"><img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa34B.png" alt="illustration"></a>
        <p>this is the paragraph ...  </p>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div style="width: 150px;">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa34B.png" align="left" width="100" height="100"> This is text  This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text This is text
  </div>
```

Comment: Added the tags to the HTML but it didn't make any difference. Is it because of CSS conflict or something else?

Comment: Yes trying removing your css

Answer (score 1):

I just use the following: float is all that's needed, a bit of padding for visuals:

```
<div class="float-right pl-3 pb-3">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/4a/c7/3b/4ac73b5c8ef5d397ab535ac1631642a7.jpg" class="shadow img-fluid">
</div>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of css code

```
display:inline;
```

Comment: tried that ... but it doen't work :( `.snippet img{
 width: 150px;
 max-width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 display:inline;

 
}

@media(max-width: 767px) {
 .snippet img{

        width:100px;
        float: right;
        max-width: 100px;
        height: auto;
        display:inline;
    }
}`

Comment: You can wrap the image inside a paragragh and it will work fine. For eg. <p><img src=""/>text here</p>

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following class to your html code: "img-responsive pull-left"

For example:

```
<img  src="IMG/img.jpg" alt="about image" class="img-rounded img-responsive pull-left">
```

Comment: This works but it has behavioural issues on bootstrap modals.