# Wrap text around an image on bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I came across an issue with wrapping the text around my image on my column.
I have a template that It's running multiple pages. some of the images are not long enough so it wont be able to over the entire column...
I realize that they are in 2 different divs but if anyone has a solution to this please let me know.

If you read and see what the issue is, you'll see its not a duplicate....

here's what my code looks like

```
    <div class="row" data-sf-element="Row">
  <div id="contentPlaceholder_C002_Col00" class="sf_colsIn col-md-6" data-sf-element="Column 1">
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply r</h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during th</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during th</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="contentPlaceholder_C002_Col01" class="col-md-6" data-sf-element="Column 2"> <img src="/images/default-source/careers/careers_1.jpg?sfvrsn=2" title="careers_1" alt="careers_1"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap - How to make text wrap around an image on small devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20676250/bootstrap-how-to-make-text-wrap-around-an-image-on-small-devices)

Comment: its not a duplicate for your info. the other question looks different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When using 2 columns the text will never get wrapped around the image.

You should put the image and text in one column and give it full with. Then wrap the text and image in a div and float them to the left. Something in the line of this (code is an example and not tested):

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="pull-left"><img src="YourImage.png"/></div>
   <div class="pull-left">Your text goes here......</div>
</div>
```

You might need some margin on the image so the text doesn't stick to close to the image

Comment: yeah thanks for the reply. i figured but thought there might be a way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<img src="img/image.jpg" class="pull-left">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste molestiae aliquam optio mollitia, unde quas eaque voluptatem dignissimos eos maiores magni reprehenderit nisi, corrupti nemo hic id cum quasi officiis!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me. My working code using rails 5.2 and bootstrap 4.1:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="<%=url_for(@user.image)%>" class="float-left" style="height:150px;margin-right:10px">
       <p>A bunch of text</p>
       <p>More text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is actually the correct answer is 2020.  the previous correct answers apparently no longer work.  it appears 'pull-left' is now 'float-left'.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 columns on this page, each with a text-wrapped image, a title, subtitle, text and link.  I nest the image in its own column within the text column to wrap the text.  This code converts to full column width when displayed on mobile.  I'm sure you could pull-right if you wanted to, but this works for me. See code in action at http://www.lbch.org/_Employment.html.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Page Head Title & Text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <img src="image" class="img-responsive" alt=""/> <br> 
      </div>
      <div class="text-left">
        <h4 class="text-center">
            <strong>Article Title</strong><br>
            <small>Article sub-title</small>
        </h4>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p><a href="link">link text</a><strong> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <img src="image" class="img-responsive" alt=""/> <br> 
      </div>
      <div class="text-left">
        <h4 class="text-center">
          <strong>Article Title</strong><br>
          <small>Article sub-title</small>
        </h4>
        <p>Text</p>
        <p><a href="link">link text</a><strong> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--row-->
</div> <!--container-->
```

Comment: You can see this code in action at http://www.lbch.org/_Employment.html.  I'm definitely not great at what I do, but it makes my boss happy and that makes me happy! LOL

Comment: Please dont put cols inside cols without a parent row! It is not valid. Have a look at [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 1):

It's far easier to just add a small margin to the image in Adobe Photoshop, then use the `img src="img/blog/image.png" class="pull-left`  The copy flows round the image without you needing to add any styling.

I just add a 10px white space to the left and bottom of the image.

Answer (score -3):

But if you want your text and image side by side, Then this would help you.

```
<div class="row">
<p class="col-md-8">Text goes here....</p>
<img class="img-circle col-md-4" src="image goes here..." alt="image text">
</div>
```

Comment: This crude solution just arranges the elements next to each other but do not wrap the text around the image what the OP asked for.