# Float column to the right using only necessary height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to implement a simple grid where an image is floating on the right, with a fluid text around it. I could achieve this just by adding the `float: right` property to the image instead of to its `col-md-6` container. However I want that if the device is a mobile phone, the image has full width using a `col-12`, that's why I need to use the column. Looking for related question in StackOverflow that's the piece of code I have right now:

```
<div class="row d-block">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 float-right">
        <img
            class="article-image ml-3 mb-1"
            src={{data.schema:thumbnailUrl}}
            onerror$="this.src={{defaultimage}}"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 float-left">
        <div class="article-body light-text">
            {{article.schema:articleBody}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiCU5.png) you can see a visual of the problem.

How can I achieve that when the image finishes the text uses the space left under it?

In other words, how can I achieve that the whole column containing the image floats to the right when using a big device mantaining the col-12 property for small ones?

Comment: You can use `col-sm-12` class which will give full width to the image when in small screens. Similarly `col-md-6 col-lg-6` when in medium and large devices. For example you can have sth like this `<img class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6"/>`

Comment: I already have that behaviour with the `col-12` class. The question is how can I achieve that the whole column containing the image floats to the right when using a big device mantaining the `col-12` property for small ones.

Comment: There is something similar here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003868/wrap-text-around-an-image-on-bootstrap-3 ) , or maybe you can use media querys for mobiles, and give a width:100% to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you make the text column full width, so you can just remove the `col-md-6`...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-block">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6  float-right">
            <img src="..." class="img-fluid" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-12"> 
        ... text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Pb0zg0Ui7m)